# how to show a value in MVC dropdownlist retrieved from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please any body tell a novice that how to show a particular value in dropdownlist from several values. For example I have India, Australia, China, England in my dropdownlist and I have updated the country as China, so when next time somebody view the detail he will see china in dropdownlist.The code in view is as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("list",ViewData["list"] as SelectList)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)
```

and Code on .cs page is as follows:

```
var list = new SelectList(new[]
                                          {
                                              new {ID="0",Name="Select"},
                                              new{ID="1",Name="Australia"},
                                              new{ID="3",Name="United States"},
                                              new {ID="4",Name="United Kingdom"},
                                              new{ID="5",Name="Europe"},
                                              new{ID="6",Name="Canada"},
                                              new {ID="7",Name="India"},
                                              new {ID="8",Name="China"},
                                              new{ID="9",Name="Japan"},
                                              new{ID="10",Name="New Zealand"},
                                          },
                            "ID", "Name", 1);
            ViewData["list"] = list;
```

Comment: why you give me minus, explain

Comment: @fealin Bawli boonch..Now see the edited code please

Comment: I really don't understand your attitude. I was not the one that downvoted this question.  I am not sure, your reaction like this one would get you what you want. I think you should try a search engine. try these terms. How to Select a value in DropDownList

Comment: @fealin please don't get me wrong buddy, I am sorry if it hurt you, I really did'nt mean that. By the way thanks for your help and guiding me..Merry christmas & tc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution which does not use ViewData,But uses viewmodels to transfer data between action methods and views. Assume you are trying to edit a customer record. So you will have a viewmodel like this

```
public class CustomerEditVM
{
  public int CustomerID { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Countries { set;get;}
  public int SelectedCountry { set;get;}
}
```

And in your action method

```
public ActionResult View(int id)
{
  var customer=repositary.GetCustomer(id);
  var customerEditVM=new CustomerEditVM { CustomerID=id,Name=customer.Name};
  customerEditVM.Countries=GetCountries();

  //Setting the selected item value here
  customerEditVM.SelectedCountry=customer.CountryID 

  return View(customerEditVM);
}
public List<SelectListItem> GetCountries()
{
  return new List<SelectListItem> {
     new SelectListItem{ Value="1",Text="India"},
     new SelectListItem{ Value="2",Text="China"},
     new SelectListItem{ Value="3",Text="US"},
  }
}
```

Your view should be strongly typed to CustomerEditVM and we will use Html.DropDownListFor helper method.

```
@model YourNamespaceHere.CustomerEditVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
 Country : 
 @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedCountry,Model.Countries,"Select")
 <input type="submit" value="Save" />
 @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.CustomerID)
}
```