# How to use create Dropdownlist in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to replace this razor code to C# and create the same function but in controller not in razor

```
    <select id="dropdownOne" name="dropdownOne" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">


        @foreach (var Category in Model.AllCategories)
    {



        if (Model.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryId).Contains(Category.CategoryId))
        {
            <option selected value="@Category.CategoryId">@Category.CategoryName</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="@Category.CategoryId">@Category.CategoryName</option>
        }
    }


    </select>
```

Comment: Why are you not just using `@Html.ListBoxFor()`?

Comment: Take a look at [how to show a value in MVC dropdownlist retrieved from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744752/how-to-show-a-value-in-mvc-dropdownlist-retrieved-from-database) or [MVC DropDownList For Selected Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31795676/mvc-dropdownlist-for-selected-value)

Comment: To create dynamic content from a list box on controller, build your own `ListBox` or `ListBoxFor` then pass `SelectList` list from controller's return view to your list box. All process logic should take place on controller and view renders result of them.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to render this dropdown in multiple pages. Put this dropdown code in Partial view or Create a Html helper class to create this dropdown. I don't understand how you create dropdown in controller